# lambda function of undertermined number of arguments

Tags: python, list

I am new to use python for programming. I want to create a function of list without determined number of arguments. My task is as follows: if I input `s=5` and `idx=[2,3]` with numerical values `[0.3, 0.7]`, it means that I have to create a list `[t0, t1, 0.3, 0.7, t4]`. The list can be treated as a function of three variables `t0, t1, and t4`. I guess I may need to use `*args`, but I do not how to do it in general.

Comment: can you give an concrete and non ambiguous example of input/output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "*args":

> > > custom_function = lambda *args: all(args)
> > > custom_function[1, 2, 3]
> > > True
> > > custom_function[1, 2, 3, 0]
> > > False
> > > Which indeed is the same as just using "all":

> > > all[1, 2, 3]
> > > True
> > > all[1, 2, 3, 0]
> > > False
> > > To be general, you can use "functools.reduce" to use any "2-parameters" function with any number of parameters (if their order doesn't matter):

import operator
import functools

c = lambda *args: functools.reduce(operator.and_, args)
(same results as before)

Comment: For simplicity, if I input s=2, t0=0.3, then how can I obtain a list c(t1)=[0.3, t1] using the above code?